# Drawing a Wave represented by (Orientation, Frequency, Phase-shift, Amplitude) Using OpenCv

Tags: opencv, c++11, visual-c++, opencv3.0

I want to create an empty image and take parameters from user, which are Wave Orientation, Wave Frequency, Phase-shift, Wave Amplitude.

And I have to give an output similar to the following image:

[image]

My questions:

- How can I draw waves inside my empty image?
- What functions should I use?

Comment: What are x,y axes? And the pixel value? what is the formula using these parameters?

Comment: i'm trying to draw in a 1024x1024 window, I don't have a formula yet this is why I wrote it here.. any help to get me started would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get those images? Do you want to convert some Matlab code or something? Without knowing what you want to draw, it's impossible to help you drawing it. Without further details this question is probably off-topic

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do the following steps (but I am not sure, since I didn't test it):

1. Use sine function with needed Wave Frequency, Phase-shift and Wave Amplitude to calculate values of pixels in one row. Possibly it will look like this with using sine and normalization:

   `for( int j = 0; j < I.cols; ++j )
        I.at<uchar>(i,j) = (Amplitude * sin(frequency*j + PhaseShift) + 1) / 2 * 255;`
2. Copy first row to other rows for receiving something like vertical lines.
3. Use `cv::getRotationMatrix2D` and `cv::warpAffine` to get needed wave orientation.