# Is there any further steps to calculate phase after dft?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, dft

I am trying to find magnitude and phase of fourier transform. There is an tutorial [Opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html). 
[image]
After using this formula, we are going to switch to a logarithmic scale and shifting normalizing. But I could not find for phase. Phase formule is :
[image] 
Here is the question after arctan calculation, do I need to do extra stuff like magnitude(log scale,shifting,normalizing)? Or what is the logic behind it I could not understand? I am programmer guy and I am very far from these Math stuff.

Comment: It's a bit surprising that you're even calculating the phase when you have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: I have a image and I have to use dft and find magnitude and phase and draw them to the screen.

Comment: homework then. Keep in mind that pixels don't have a range (−π, π

Comment: Your prof seems not that good at teaching :D Your classmates are lost as well: [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368793/how-can-i-create-a-wave-with-defining-the-degrees-frequency-phase-shift-deg?lq=1), [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278533/drawing-a-wave-represented-by-orientation-frequency-phase-shift-amplitude-u)

Answer (score 1):

The `arctan` range is  `(−π, π]`. Hint: use `std::atan2`. You may indeed shift this to `[0, 2*π)` if you like. This is in no way necessary, it just avoids negative numbers.

Scaling to 360 degrees is also possible, but very rare - math is always done in radians, degrees are only for human consumption, and which human is going to look at FFT magnitudes?

Log scales are utterly pointless for angles, as they are modulo 2π.

Comment: One technique that is sometimes applied after `atan2` is "phase unwrapping", for systems where you want some sort of absolute phase measurement which might fall outside the 2π range.

Comment: @PaulR: I don't think we have the information available here to do that, do we?

Comment: The question is quite vague, so I have no idea what the OP is looking for in particular. It seems that phase unwrapping is used for things like [MRI](http://www1.coe.neu.edu/~erdogmus/publications/C129_MLSP2008_PhaseUnwrapping4MRI_Tian.pdf) though.